# Restoring VPC peering for private GKE cluster

Tags: gke-networking

Private GKE clusters reuse VPC peering connection from worker nodes to master nodes in Google-managed VPC project/network.

Accidentally this VPC peering was removed and worker nodes lost connection to master API.

Is there a way to restore that VPC peering? I could see removal action log at Cloud Activity page, but it doesn't look too helpful as it doesn't contain before/after state, so it's not evident which project/network should be set to restore peering.
Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to get it working by creating a brand new private GKE cluster in the same vpc. Google has created vpc peering with a master subnet of a new cluster together with recently removed master subnet. Hopefully, it looks like they use the same vpc/network for a peering to a specific customer vpc. Then removed temporary created cluster.

Comment: @ Mihail could you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a good practice here to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Sure, thanks [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17894104/leo) and [Hector Martinez Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16923081/hector-martinez-rodriguez).

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working by creating a brand new private GKE cluster in the same vpc. Google has created vpc peering with a master subnet of a new cluster together with recently removed master subnet. Hopefully, it looks like they use the same vpc/network for a peering to a specific customer vpc. Then removed temporary created cluster.

P.S. Thanks [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17894104/leo) and 
[Hector Martinez Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16923081/hector-martinez-rodriguez) for pointing to the best practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I found this behavior is actually documented here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#network_peering_reuse